# LPTHW ex50:Can't find module utils

Tags: python

I'm at exercise 50 of lpthw [this is the link](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex50.html).
And after having downloaded the lpthw.web framework in a very messy way.
I continued the exercise by writing a .py file.

```
import web
urls = ('/', 'index')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class index:
    def GET(self):
        greeting = "Hello World"
        return greeting

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

but i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "bin\app.py", line 1, in <module>
      import web
    File "c:\Python31\lib\site-packages\web\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
      import utils, db, net, wsgi, http, webapi, httpserver, debugerror
ImportError: No module named utils
```

What is the problem caused by,

I suspect it is the very messy way with wich I installed lpthw.web (I got a lot of errors, but tried multiple ways multiple times.)
Thank you in advance!
If anybody needs more info comment so I can edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot to read the setup instructions. This learning guide is **not** python3 compatible:

[Exercise 0: The Setup](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex0.html)

> You should follow these instructions as exactly as possible. For
> example, Mac OSX computers already have Python 2, so do not install
> Python 3 (or any Python).
>
> *Make sure you install Python 2 not Python 3.*
>
> **Warnings For Beginners**
> A programmer may try to get you to install Python 3 and learn that. You should tell them, "When all of the python code on your computer is Python 3, then I'll try to learn it." That should keep them busy for about 10 years.

Remove python3 from your system and install python2.7 to allow this tutorial to work when you install suggested packages.

Otherwise, find another tutorial that is using examples from libararies that are python3 compatable. Not everything is updated as of right now. Many people stick to python2.7 for this reason.

Comment: why are you telling me this! Is this because of a compability problem because I do have python3 instead of python2 but it hasn't caused me a real problem until maybe now?

Comment: I am telling you this as a direct quote from the website you are using for your tutorial. It is not python3 compatable. So when you start installing other packages that dont work with py3 they fail. Many existing packages do not work yet. Its a slow progress of people updating. Thats why many people stay on python2.7. I already knew you had python3.1 from your paths. Its the reason the web framework isnt installing. Remove it and install python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

As the tutorial state, you can try installing using `easy_install` or `pip` from the command line it would be `easy_install lpthw.web` or `pip install lpthw.web`

Also note that you need to properly reference `application`  
this `app = application(urls, globals())` should be 
 
`app = web.application(urls, globals())`
note the ^^^ part.

Also if you are interested in python micro-web-frameworks I recommend [bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/), it doesn't need to be installed its just a single python file called `bottle.py`

**Update**
I managed to recreate the problem using python3, so `jdi` was right, the problem here is that python3 isn't backwards compatible with python2, some python2 complaint applications won't properly run under python3 and vice-versa.

In this case python3 doesn't seem to support relative imports within package, did find this http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/ which was kind of interesting.

exert from the pep:

> For the second problem, it is proposed that all import statements be absolute by default (searching sys.path only) with special syntax (leading dots) for accessing package-relative imports.

so `lpthw.web` tries to import relative packages but it simply can't.
which is why we get `ImportError: No module named utils` since utils is relative module within the package.
even if it could loaded it, it will stumble with other non-backwards compatibility issues, just trying to `import utils` within the package we get

```
>>> import utils 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "utils.py", line 75
    except KeyError, k:
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

which is related to this pep http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/ which states different syntax to the `except` statement.

As you can see it will be a major hurdle trying to migrate this package to python3 so much so thats its better to leave it to the developers, this goes for the many many packages out there, why is python3 so different from python2, well mainly because they wanted to patch the language as much as possible ...

For the time being stick to python2, eventually most packages will be migrated to python3.

Comment: I already did use pip to install lpthw.web and the code already had web.appliction(...) but I'm sorry just copied it wrong.Any Ideas??

Comment: @user1544624 the problem is that `lpthw.web` can't be used with python3 only python2, I've updated the answer, I hope it helps.