# Import Error: No module named 'utils' when running a script with the lpthw.web framework

Tags: python, web, frameworks

I am new to python and I am following "Learn Python the Hard Way" by Zed Shaw. In chapter 50, he asks you to download the lpthw.web framework and run the following the program I listed on the bottom. However, when I try to do so, I get the following error. The book recommended using Python 2 but I decided to try Python 3. I am on a windows 7 computer. If the problem is that I am using Python 3, is there a way to make that framework Python 3 friendly or which other one is recommended for someone learning. Thank you very much for the help.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import web
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\web\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import utils, db, net, wsgi, http, webapi, httpserver, debugerror
ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

Program:

```
 import web

 urls = (
 '/', 'index'
 )

 app = web.application(urls, globals())

 class index:
     def GET(self):
         greeting = "Hello World"
         return greeting

 if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LPTHW ex50:Can't find module utils](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910347/lpthw-ex50cant-find-module-utils)

Comment: I guess you should just use python2 instead

Answer (score -2):

`pip install utils` would solve your problem :)